# Store grep output containing whitespaces in an array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, grep, whitespace

I want to store some lines of the output of `blkid` in an array. The problem is, that those lines contain whitespace and the array syntax takes those as delimiters for single array elements, so that i end up with splitted lines in my array instead of one line beeing one array element.

This is the code i currently have:
`devices=($(sudo blkid | egrep '^/dev/sd[b-z]'))`

`echo ${devices[*]}` gives me the following output:

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="ARCH_201108" TYPE="udf"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="WD" UUID="414ECD7B314A557F" TYPE="ntfs"
```

But `echo ${#devices[*]}` gives me `7` but insted i want to have `2`. I want `/dev/sdb1: LABEL="ARCH_201108" TYPE="udf"` to be the first element in my devices array and `/dev/sdc1: LABEL="WD" UUID="414ECD7B314A557F" TYPE="ntfs"` to be the second one. How can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Array elements are split on the IFS value. If you want to split on newline, adjust IFS:

```
IFS_backup=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
devices=($(sudo blkid | egrep '^/dev/sd[b-z]'))
IFS=$IFS_backup
echo ${#devices[@]}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exaclty what i was looking for.

Comment: I am glad that people like you exist: thank you for the answer :)

Comment: IFS=$'\n'
***your code here***
unset IFSET